# Unable to Set Root Store in Feature Module while Testing

Tags: angular, angular5, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

**Here is the imports into component test**

```
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [
            RouterTestingModule,
            StoreModule.forRoot({companies: combineReducers(fromStore.reducers), ...fromRootStore.reducers}),
            EffectsModule.forRoot([CompanyEffects, CollectionEffects]),
            StoreRouterConnectingModule
          ],
          providers: [
            CompanyService,
            ...fromCompanyGuards.guards,
            {provide: RouterStateSerializer, useClass: CustomSerializer}
          ],
          declarations: [ CompanySummaryComponent, CompanyHeaderComponent ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
      }));
```

**My Test**

```
    it('should create', () => {
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

**My Component:**

```
    constructor(
        private store: Store,
        private rootStore: Store
        ) {

        this.actionsSubscription = this.store.select(fromRootStore.getRouterState)
          .pipe(map((routerState: fromRouter.RouterReducerState) =>
            new company.Select(routerState.state.params.companyId)))
          .subscribe(store);

    }
```

**root store state:**

```
    export interface State {
      routerReducer: fromRouter.RouterReducerState;
      user: fromUserReducer.UserState;
    }
```

**Root Reducer:**

```
    export const reducers: ActionReducerMap = {
      routerReducer: fromRouter.routerReducer,
      user: fromUserReducer.reducer
    };
```

**selector for router reducer:**

```
    export const getRouterState = createFeatureSelector('routerReducer');
```

**this selector returning undefined in component tests but it works fine in application.
**

**I tried different combinations with importing store module in tests**

```
    1) StoreModule.forRoot({companies: combineReducers(fromStore.reducers), ...fromRootStore.reducers}),

    2) StoreModule.forRoot(combineReducers({companies: combineReducers(fromStore.reducers), ...fromRootStore.reducers})),

    3) 1) StoreModule.forRoot(...companies: combineReducers(fromStore.reducers), ...fromRootStore.reducers),
```

**Note: I tired even accessing only user from the root store and it is also not working.**
**I'm using ngrx 4.1.1 version.**